# Handle MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE and MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE in the same @PostMapping in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have an endpoint that get POST requests with the same parameters but encoded different ways. Can I combine them?

```
  public static class V1PostStatus {
        public String status;
        public String[] media_ids;
        public V1PostPoll poll;
        public String in_reply_to_id;
        public boolean sensitive;
        public String spoiler_text;
        public String visibility;
        public String language;
        public String scheduled_at;
        public static class V1PostPoll {
            public String[] options;
            public int expires_in;
            public boolean multiple;
            public boolean hide_totals;
        }
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/statuses", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> postApiV1Statuses(Principal user, @RequestBody V1PostStatus body) {
```

and

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/statuses", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> postApiV1Statuses(Principal user, @RequestPart(name = "status") String status,
                                                   @RequestPart(name = "media_ids", required = false) String[] media_ids, @RequestPart(name = "poll", required = false) V1PostStatus.V1PostPoll poll, @RequestPart(name = "in_reply_to_id", required = false) String in_reply_to_id, @RequestPart(name = "sensitive", required = false) String sensitive, @RequestPart(name = "spoiler_text", required = false) String spoiler_text, @RequestPart(name = "visibility") String visibility, @RequestPart(name = "language") String language, @RequestPart(name = "scheduled_at", required = false) String scheduled_at) {
```

I'm wondering if there is some Spring Boot magic to only write the function once and either have Spring Boot expand the JSON to parameters and call the form version or translate the form into JSON and call the JSON version.

Tragically, we have various endpoints like this were some clients will send form data and others will send JSON.

I tried just doing the JSON version without the consumes attribute, but it didn't work with form data.

Answer (score 0):

i did a bunch of code crawls and figured out that resolver for @RequestBody explicitly disallows this. i ended up creating a new annotation @RequestObject that resolves both JSON and URL to object mappings with URL parameters. it turned out to be pretty easy.